# Confused with REDUX actions and reducers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

so I am trying to refactor some code from my previous question:

[React: How to update one component, when something happens on another component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54902665/react-how-to-update-one-component-when-something-happens-on-another-component)

So I started digging deep into the existing code template  to see how it was implemented.

I found a reducers.js where I added a new reducer: ActiveTenant

```
import Auth from './auth/reducer';
import App from './app/reducer';
import ThemeSwitcher from './themeSwitcher/reducer';
import LanguageSwitcher from './languageSwitcher/reducer';
import ActiveTenant from './activetenant/reducer';

export default {
  Auth,
  App,
  LanguageSwitcher,
  ThemeSwitcher,
  ActiveTenant
};
```

That  new reducer is like this:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import actions from './actions';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';

const initState = new Map({
    tenantId: ''
});

export default function(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.SET_TENANT_ACTIVE:
    {
        const options = { 
            method: 'post'
        };

        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant/SetTenantActive?TenantName="+state.tenantId, options)
        .then(response =>{
            if(response.status === 200){
                console.log("Tenant activated");
            }else{
                throw "error";
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

        return state.set('tenant', state.Name);
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

and actions for that reducer

```
const actions = {
  SET_TENANT_ACTIVE: 'SET_TENANT_ACTIVE',
  setTenantActive: () => ({
    type: actions.SET_TENANT_ACTIVE
  }),
};
export default actions;
```

Then from the component itself, I need to call the action when a row is selected on the front end, so I have refactored the commented code, into one line.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  Table, Radio} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';
import actions from '../../redux/activetenant/actions';

const { setTenantActive } = actions;

class ListTenants extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: []
        };
    }



    fetchData = () => {
        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", {})
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(responseJson => {
            if (!this.isCancelled) {
                const results= responseJson.map(row => ({
                    key: row.id,
                    TestSiteCollectionUrl: row.TestSiteCollectionUrl,
                    TenantName: row.TenantName,
                    Email: row.Email
                  }))
              this.setState({ data: results });
            }
          })
          .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      };


    componentDidMount(){
        this.fetchData();
    }

    render() {
        const columns = [
                {
                    title: 'TenantName',
                    dataIndex: 'TenantName',
                    key: 'TenantName',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'TestSiteCollectionUrl',
                    dataIndex: 'TestSiteCollectionUrl',
                    key: 'TestSiteCollectionUrl',
                }, 
                {
                    title: 'Email',
                    dataIndex: 'Email',
                    key: 'Email',
                }
        ];

        // rowSelection object indicates the need for row selection
        const rowSelection = {
            onChange: (selectedRowKeys, selectedRows) => {
                if(selectedRows[0].TenantName != undefined){
                    console.log(selectedRows[0].TenantName);
                    const options = { 
                        method: 'post'
                    };

                    setTenantActive(selectedRows[0].TenantName);
                    /* adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant/SetTenantActive?TenantName="+selectedRows[0].TenantName.toString(), options)
                        .then(response =>{
                        if(response.status === 200){
                            Notification(
                                'success',
                                'Tenant set to active',
                                ''
                                );
                        }else{
                            throw "error";
                        }
                        })
                        .catch(error => {
                        Notification(
                            'error',
                            'Tenant not activated',
                            error
                            );
                        console.error(error);
                    }); */
                }
            },
            getCheckboxProps: record => ({
                type: Radio
            }),
        };

        return (
            <Table rowSelection={rowSelection} columns={columns} dataSource={this.state.data} />
        );
    }
}

export default ListTenants;
```

However, its not clear to me the relationship between the action and the reducer, if I check the debugger the action is executed, and none parameter is received, but the reducer is never executed.

DO i have to put a dispatch somewhere?, what I am missing in this puzzle?

Comment: This article really helped me understand the differences and it's entertaining as well https://link.medium.com/OYJvQWEapwb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first thing to understand is the **Redux Cycle**:

**Action Creator-->Action-->dispatch-->Reducers-->State**

**Action Creator**: An action creator is a function that is going to create or return a plain JavaScript object knowns as an **Action** with a `type` property and `payload` property which describes some change you want to make on your data.

The `payload` property describes some context around the change we want to make.

The purpose of an **Action** is to describe some change to the data inside our application.

The **Action Creator** is to create the **Action**.

The `dispatch` function is going to take in an **Action** and make copies of that object and pass it off to a bunch of different places inside our application which leads us to the **Reducers**.

In Redux, a reducer is a function responsible for taking in an **Action**. It's going to process that **Action**, make some change to the data and return it so it can be centralized in some location.

In Redux, the **State** property is a central repository of all information produced by our **reducers**. All the information gets consolidated inside the **State** object so our React application can easily reach into our Redux side of the app and get access to all the data inside the application.

So this way the app does not have to go around to each separate reducer and ask for the current **State**.

So digest that for a couple of minutes and then look at your architecture.

Let's skip over to **reducers**.

**Reducers** are called with an **Action** that was created by an **Action Creator**. The reducer will take a look at that **Action** and decide whether it needs to modify some data based on that **Action**.

So in other words, the job of a reducer is not to execute API requests but to process actions sent to it by the action creator.

So instead of this:

```
import { Map } from 'immutable';
import actions from './actions';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';

const initState = new Map({
    tenantId: ''
});

export default function(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actions.SET_TENANT_ACTIVE:
    {
        const options = { 
            method: 'post'
        };

        adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant/SetTenantActive?TenantName="+state.tenantId, options)
        .then(response =>{
            if(response.status === 200){
                console.log("Tenant activated");
            }else{
                throw "error";
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

        return state.set('tenant', state.Name);
    }
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Your reducer should look something like this:

```
import { SET_TENANT_ACTIVE } from "../actions/types";

const initialState = {
    tenantId: ''
};

export default (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_TENANT_ACTIVE:
      return {...state, [action.payload.id]: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Then inside your action creators file, you should have an action creator that looks something like this:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { SET_TENANT_ACTIVE } from "../actions/types";


export const setTenant = id => async (dispatch) => {
  const response = await axios.post(`/tenants/${id}`);

  dispatch({ type: SET_TENANT_ACTIVE, payload: response.data });
};
```

You also need to learn about Redux project structure because after the above refactor, you are missing how to wire all this up to your component. In your component file there is no `connect()` function which also requires the `Provider` tag and you have none of that.

So for this I recommend first of all your set up your folder and file structure like so:

```
  /src
    /actions
    /components
    /reducers
    index.js
```

So inside your `index.js` file it should look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import reduxThunk from "redux-thunk";

import App from "./components/App";
import reducers from "./reducers";

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducers,
  composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(reduxThunk))
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
```

So your goal here is to ensure that you get that `Provider` tag at the very top of your component hierarchy and ensure that you pass it a reference to your Redux store that gets all the **reducers** loaded up into it.

So above I have created the store and passed it our set of reducers and it will return back to you all your applications **State**.

Lastly, what you see above is I created an instance of `<Provider>` and wrapped the `<App />` component with it and then you want to pass the `<Provider>` component is a single prop called `store`. The `store` is the result of calling `createStore()` and calling the `reducers`.

The `<Provider>` is what interacts with the Redux `store` on our behalf.

Notice, I also have wired up Redux-Thunk that J. Hesters mentioned, you are making an ajax request as far as I can see from your code which is why I offered an asynchronous action creator for you, which means you will need Redux-Thunk or some middleware like that, let me not offend the Redux-Saga fans, so you have those two choice at least. You seem relatively new to Redux, just go with Redux-Thunk.

Now you can use the `connect()` component inside your component file to finish wiring up those action creators and reducers to your component or your React side of the application.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import {  Table, Radio} from 'antd';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';
import Notification from '../../components/notification';
import actions from '../../redux/activetenant/actions';
```

After importing `connect`, you create an instance of it below:

```
export default connect()(ListTenants);
```

Please don't argue with me on the above syntax (*actually had a former student report me to administrators for using this syntax as evidence of not knowing what I was doing*).

Then you need to configure this `connect()` React component by adding `mapStateToProps` if you are going to need it, but definitely pass in `actions` as the second argument to `connect()`. If you realize you don't need `mapStateToProps`, then just pass in `null` as the first argument, but you can't leave it empty.

Answer (score 1):

You are using reducers wrong. Reducers are [supposed to be pure.](https://redux.js.org/introduction/three-principles#changes-are-made-with-pure-functions) Yours has side-effects showing that you haven't understood Redux, yet.

Instead of writing down a solution for you (which would take forever anyways since one would have to explain Redux in total), I suggest you invest the 3 hours and go through the Redux docs and follow the [tutorials](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) (they are great).

Afterwards you might want to look into [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk). But, [you might not need thunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411423/how-to-dispatch-a-redux-action-with-a-timeout/35415559#35415559).

PS: (Small thing to bring up, but I haven't seen anyone using `Map`s in Redux. Is there a reason you do that? You might want to use plain objects instead.)

Answer (score 1):

Your action is not correct you should pass an active tenant name as parameter.

Ref. https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/createaction

We could have written the action types as inline strings in both places.
The action creators are good, but they're not required to use Redux - a component could skip supplying a mapDispatch argument to connect, and just call this.props.dispatch({type : "CREATE_POST", payload : {id : 123, title : "Hello World"}}) itself.

Ref. https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/usage/usage-guide